# cURL Login Apple

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to do a cURL Login to Apple but I don't have any ideea what I have to do in this case.

When I run the script I get this error

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains Content-Security-Policy: default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.apple.com https://*.cdn-apple.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https://*.apple.com https://*.cdn-apple.com; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: https://*.apple.com https://*.cdn-apple.com https://*.icloud.com https://*.mzstatic.com http://appleid-localdev.apple.com:19380; X-BuildVersion: R3 Set-Cookie: aa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omain=idmsa.apple.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly Content-Length: 0 Vary: Accept-Encoding Date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 15:49:29 GMT Server: Apple Set-Cookie: X-SESS=28d4a3dabbd9885122f543812c1be5cd88709143b8732f334e78597f994adfb94b10456f;Version=1;Max-Age=1800;path=/;secure;httponly

And this is my code

```
<?php
$username = 'mail@mail.com';
$pass = 'password';

$login = array(
    'accountName' => $username,
    'password' => $pass,
    'rememberMe' => 'false'
);

$loginUrl = 'https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Accept-Encoding: gzip',
                                            'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                                            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
                                            'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                            ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($login));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://idmsa.apple.com/appleauth/auth/signin?widgetKey=af1139274f266b22b68c2a3e7ad932cb3c0bbe854e13a79af78dcc73136882c3&locale=en_EN&rv=1
');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

$content1 = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
echo $content1;

?>
```

Any suggestions ? Thank you .